# I can not read an Excel cell having a leading apostrophe within it

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledb

I faced such a problem. I trying to read Excel file data, all are as a string. I used code bellow.

```
try
{
    var connectionString = string.Format( "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"", session["FilePath"] );
    using (var adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter( "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connectionString ))
    {
        var ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill( ds, "workBook" );
        workBook = ds.Tables["workBook"];
    }
    if (workBook == null)
        throw new Exception( "Could not load imported spreadsheet!" );
    if (workBook.Rows.Count <= 0)
        throw new Exception( "You are use an empty spreadsheet!" );
    foreach (DataColumn column in workBook.Columns)
        column.ColumnName = column.ColumnName.Trim();
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
}
```

All worked fine, I was getting a datatable with data as a string data type and was parsing them on program level (I just have a mixed data types in one column). But when the cell have a Number format and value of this cell, for example, is 0589, I need to add a leading apostrophe in a cell because 0 must be present in 4-digit number. When I tried read such excel file using a IMEX parameter 1, I have got NULL value from this cell. I don't understand why, I read all data as a string data type.

Comment: Have you tried with a different provider? `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;`?

Comment: Not sure that this provider is installed on the client machine. I'm only sure of Microsoft Jet 4.0.

Comment: Hm.. ok have you tried loading the data into an ADO.Recordset instead of a datatable?

Comment: No, I'm not tried. Can I then import the data from an ADO.Recordset to Datatable? Because my code is working with the datatable.

Comment: Just tried to load excel data to the Recordset and same cell returns NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I fixed that, before loading spreadsheet I set the registry key TypeGuessRows to zero on the program level and after loading back to 8 (in case other programs will use it).

Answer (score 0):

Change the number format of the cells to "0000" for a number that will always be 4 digits and retain the leading zeros.

Comment: Unfortunately my client wants that on his side all worked fine without any manipulation with the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

```
     string file = "C:\\temp\\Exposure\\UTC.xlsx";
        OleDbConnectionStringBuilder connStringBuilder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
        connStringBuilder.DataSource = file;
        connStringBuilder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";

        connStringBuilder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1");

        DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");

        DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = connStringBuilder.ConnectionString;
        connection.Open();

        // var myTableName = connection.GetSchema("Tables").Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"];

        DbCommand selectCommand = factory.CreateCommand();

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Daily Monitoring$]";
        selectCommand.CommandText = sql;
        selectCommand.Connection = connection;

        DbDataAdapter adapter = factory.CreateDataAdapter();

        adapter.SelectCommand = selectCommand;
        DataSet data = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(data);
        DataTable dt = data.Tables[0];

        connection.Close();
        string ss = dt.Rows[1][1].ToString();
```