# VB6 Import data from XLS - Values Returned as NULL

Tags: excel, import, null, vb6, xls

i'am trying to import into VB6 data from a XLS file, and some data are returned as null, when there is data on the cell

i have to record the data in the XLS file as Text, because i have the need to have zeros on the left

my XLS file looks like this:

[image: XLS File Image]

Some cells have an error:
Numbers Formatted as text or proceded by an apostrophe
and this are the cells that are null in VB6

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim oRs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim sConString As String
Dim sXLFile As String
Dim vValue As Variant

sXLFile = "T:\BC\dev\howto_read_excel\ArtigosCampanha\Promoção Mês Criança_1_2015_2015 05 25_2015 06 28_CM.xls"
sConString = "Provider= Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & " Data Source=" & sXLFile & ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection

With oConn
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open sConString
End With

Set oRs = New ADODB.Recordset

With oRs
    .CursorType = adOpenStatic
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .LockType = adLockPessimistic
    .Source = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
    .ActiveConnection = oConn
    .Open
    .MoveFirst
End With

Dim refer As String
Dim cb As String

Do While Not oRs.EOF
'   oRS ("CodBarras")
   refer = IIf(IsNull(oRs.Fields.item("Referencia").value), "NULL", oRs.Fields.item("Referencia").value)
   cb = IIf(IsNull(oRs.Fields.item("CodBarras").value), "NULL", oRs.Fields.item("CodBarras").value)

   'use refer and cb where with some  function
oRs.MoveNext
Loop

oRs.Close
oConn.Close

Set oRs = Nothing
Set oConn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Can some one help me?

Comment: just out of curiosity, try rewriting the code to remove the use of IIf and replace with regular if statements. If I recall correctly, IIf in vb6 can behave strangely.

Comment: You could try using the IMEX extended property, or try the registry update that instructs Excel to inspect more than the first 8 rows to determine data types (note: could negatively impact performance).  See http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/#microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0 for a description of both.

Comment: also see this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972973/i-can-not-read-an-excel-cell-having-a-leading-apostrophe-within-it

Answer (score 0):

You can bring all of the CodBarras field items in as text or bring all of them in as numbers if the rogue values can ALWAYS be converted to true numbers. The text-that-look-like-numbers are being discarded by the overhead that is trying to avoid a crash.

```
'as text
.Source = "SELECT [Referencia], CStr([CodBarras]) FROM [Sheet1$]"
'as numbers
.Source = "SELECT [Referencia], CLng([CodBarras]) FROM [Sheet1$]"
```

Those are VBA/MS Access conversion codes. T-SQL would be close to,

```
'as text
.Source = "SELECT [Referencia], CONVERT(varchar(16), [CodBarras]) FROM [Sheet1$]"
'as numbers
.Source = "SELECT [Referencia], CONVERT(int, [CodBarras]) FROM [Sheet1$]"
```

Comment: .Source = "SELECT [Referencia], CONVERT(varchar(16), [CodBarras]) FROM [Sheet1$]" 

this does not work =( 
because is not a sql query